# SQL query to remove unwanted pieces

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi I have this table called **agents2** and it is structured as follows,

```
agents2
---------------
id , title
```

Under the table.title there are couple of records which contains (www/http..etc) For an example

```
title= www.postgre.com
```

what I'd like to see is

```
title= postgre.com
```

Is there a query where If I  execute  that would remove `www.` part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What database?  Most will have some sort of locate in string function. Combine that with substringing.

Comment: Hi Andrew i'm on sqlite.thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in SQL Server

```
SELECT REPLACE ( title , 'www.' , '' ), id from agents2
```

For example

```
SELECT REPLACE ( 'www.example.com' , 'www.' , '' )
```

will give you 'example.com'

Unfortunately, it will replace all occurrences of 'www.'

For example

```
SELECT REPLACE ( 'www.examplewww.com' , 'www.' , '' )
```

will give you 'examplecom'

For further examples, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: hi Rumman thanks for your reply.I'm using sqlite.I'll try this query.thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE agents2 SET title = replace(title, 'www.', '') WHERE title LIKE 'www.%';
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e7f2e/1)

**SQLite (WebSQL) Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE agents2
    ("id" INTEGER, "title" TEXT(24));

INSERT INTO agents2 ("id", "title") VALUES (1, 'www.postgre.com');
INSERT INTO agents2 ("id", "title") VALUES (2, 'http://stackoverflow.com');
INSERT INTO agents2 ("id", "title") VALUES (3, 'http://www.sqlfiddle.com');
INSERT INTO agents2 ("id", "title") VALUES (4, 'http://www.com-www.com/');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REPLACE ( ' '||REPLACE ( title , 'http://' , '' ) , ' www.' , '' )
FROM agents2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e7f2e/1/0)**:

```
| REPLACE ( ' '||REPLACE ( title , 'http://' , '' ) , ' www.' , '' ) |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                        postgre.com |
|                                                  stackoverflow.com |
|                                                      sqlfiddle.com |
|                                                       com-www.com/ |
```

Comment: Wow thanks fabien. Thats very helpful and very descriptive. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has an instr() function.  So:

```
instr('title= www.postgre.com','www')
```

will return the start position of 'www'.  You should be able to use that, along with substring and concatenation to get the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

SEB BINFIELD answered my question.Exactly what i needed.And thanks Fabien for extremely useful and easier-to-grasp solution.

```
UPDATE agents2 SET title = replace(title, 'www.', '') WHERE title LIKE 'www.%';
```

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE` will remove all occurrences of string in title.

This will only remove string in beginning.

```
UPDATE agents2 SET title = SUBSTR(title, 8) WHERE title LIKE 'http://%';
UPDATE agents2 SET title = SUBSTR(title, 5) WHERE title LIKE 'www.%';
```